# Why is 'God forbid (that)' followed by a 'should' clause?

Tags: grammar

Why is 'God forbid (that)' followed by a 'should' clause? What is the grammatical explanation? Does it have anything to do with the Subjunctive Mood again? In [which](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/should) sense is the word used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your dictionary link, the sense used in this expression is:

> 3. formal (expressing the conditional mood) **referring to a possible event or situation.**
>    ‘if you should change your mind, I'll be at the hotel’

When people say "God forbid [x] should happen" it idiomatically means they hope that it doesn't happen. Literally, it is asking that God does not allow it to happen, but it is worth noting that the expression has become a figure of speech that is widely used and does not necessarily indicate a belief in God.

Comment: So I'm not supposed to avoid 'should' in that phrase, am I?

Comment: You don't have to use 'should'. You could say "god forbid that happens", "god forbid that *ever* happens", or "god forbid that *were* to happen". Lots of choices.